# MySQL: Select multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

If SQL query contains all fields what I need it will be very large.
How in SQL query I can select field from F3 to F 100 and from F150 to F200?

```
SELECT F3 to F100, F150 to F200 FROM database;
```

It is possible or not???
Tables structure change is not available

Comment: SELECT * FROM database

Comment: That sounds like a bad table design. Would it be possible to change it?

Comment: I dont think you can have shortcut, and also as mentioned by @juergen seems to be a bad table design. Can you post your table structure?

Comment: Is there any magic you could think of column which should be part? maybe something like each second or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You have to :

1- manually select all columns . Or

2- do

```
    Select * from database
```

And then just fetch the columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are no shortcuts for this, you will have to list the fields needed one way or another. If the fields being selected are always the same, you should create a view for that as:

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView AS
SELECT
    F3,
    ...
    F100
FROM
    SomeTable
```

and then select like:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeView
```

But again, you will have to list the fields at least once.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT F3 to F100, F150 to F200 FROM database;

this query can not possible..

you must have to specify all the columns name

like select F1,f2,f3 from database;

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

But if it's not possible to modify your table structure to fix the database design issue, you can use an SQL query to generate the MySQL query:

```
 SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), ' FROM `your table`') 
 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your schema' and TABLE_NAME = 'your table'
 GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

Add a filter in WHERE to select only the desired fields.